# Which test management Jira Add-On can be used which has cucumber integration?

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, jira, jira-plugin, manual-testing

I am evaluating Test management tool (a Jira Add-On) which can used to store Requirements, Manual Test Cases as well as Cucumber feature file for automation.

I have evaluated Xray and it looks promising but i want to play with more such tools before i show a presentation to client. Zephyr, TestRail and HipTest are others in the list to be evaluated. Can anyone suggest a good tool which i can dig into.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you find any promising tool?

Comment: Hey, Integrated X-ray with Jira and its very promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [AssertThat BDD & Test Management in Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219033/assertthat-bdd-test-management-in-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)

Provides end-to-end integration - from features creation to manual and automated tests execution and reporting. Out of the box integration with test automation frameworks through plugins.

More info and usage examples on website https://www.assertthat.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would explore Cucumber Pro, which is an addition to Cucumber. More information is available at https://cucumber.io/pro

Answer (score 0):

We have evaluated Zephyr, Testrail and Hitpest. We have chosen Hiptest because that’s the only tool to enable refactoring of your BDD scenarios. They have just published a [blog post on the subject](https://blog.hiptest.net/2016/05/26/getting-started-with-bdd-part-2/)
It manages both manual and automated test execution.